# Offline Transaction Signing with Fabric Node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Has anyone successfully implemented offline transaction signing using the tutorial from  current master(version 2.2) of the Fabric Node SDK?
I am following these tutorials for the proposal construction and offline signing  of the proposal.

v2.2: https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/master/tutorial-sign-transaction-offline.html
https://github.com/BLOCKOTUS/hyperledger-fabric-offline-transaction-signing

I am running into the following errors

```
2021-09-15T11:37:15.283Z - error: [Endorser]: sendProposal[peer0.org2.example.com:9051] - Received error response from: grpcs://localhost:9051 error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error validating proposal: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
2021-09-15T11:37:15.283Z - error: [Endorser]: sendProposal[peer0.org2.example.com:9051] - rejecting with: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error validating proposal: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
2021-09-15T11:37:15.284Z - error: [Endorser]: sendProposal[peer0.org1.example.com:7051] - Received error response from: grpcs://localhost:7051 error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error validating proposal: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
2021-09-15T11:37:15.284Z - error: [Endorser]: sendProposal[peer0.org1.example.com:7051] - rejecting with: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error validating proposal: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
```

And in the peer logs following log is recorded

```
2021-09-15 11:37:15.282 UTC [endorser] Validate -> WARN 097 access denied: creator's signature over the proposal is not valid: The signature is invalid channel=mychannel txID=1b2ca125 mspID=Org1MSP
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a little different to the steps described by the tutorial. You are generating the hash as:

```
const proposalBytes = endorsement.build(idx, build_options);
const proposalDigest = user.getCryptoSuite().hash(proposalBytes.toString(), { algorithm: 'SHA2' });
```

You need a SHA256 hash of the exact message bytes, not converted into a string. So using Node's *crypto* library, something like:

```
const digest = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(proposalBytes).digest();
```

Recent versions of the *elliptic* package can take care of preventing malleability for you by specifying the `canonical` option, something like:

```
const curve = new EC('p256');
const keyPair = curve.keyFromPrivate(prvKeyHex, 'hex');
const signature = curve.sign(digest, keyPair, { canonical: true });
const signatureBytes = Buffer.from(signature.toDER());
```